# onclick = window.location anchor jumps to top

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I had a complicated situation that involved a variety of sliders that just wouldn't work as tabbed content even though it was designed that way, on a one page wordpress site.

The site is here: http://carubba.brandconstructors.com/  and the "project" section is the issue.

So I made different wordpress page templates for each category. I used onlick=window.location to navigate through the so-called tabs. However, when you click through to the next tab, the page jumps to the very top for a brief second then back down. Is there a way to make this not happen and go straight to the anchor location? I tried adding return false, and javascript:void(0) and that didn't work either.

Here is the code for the links:

```
<ul class="projects-cat">
            <li><a href="#" id="project-gallery" onclick="window.location = '/commercial/#projects';">Commercial</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="project-gallery" onclick="window.location = '/marine/#projects';">Marine</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="project-gallery" onclick="window.location = '/institutional/#projects';">Institutional</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="project-gallery" onclick="window.location = '/civil/#projects';">Civil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="project-gallery" onclick="window.location = '/specialty/#projects';">Specialty</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="project-gallery" onclick="window.location = '/residential/#projects';">Residential</a></li>


        </ul>
```

Any help would be awesome.

**EDIT***
This is in the footer:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.projects-cat li a').click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
       });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Hola, Can you share more code, such the `js` in charge of the tabs?

Comment: You shouldn't use an id more than once on a page (project-gallery)

Comment: I inherited this 3/4 of the way through so was just trying to piece the final content together (as easy and fast as possible). But maybe ajax would be the way to go.

Comment: Why are you using `<a href="#"` and JavaScript instead of just linking normally?!

Answer (score 0):

No, the browser is always going to jump down as it renders the page and calculates how far down to move.

You should stay on the same page, and either load all content, and hide and show as needed, or load the content for each page via AJAX.

Comment: Maybe an ajax solution would work. There were crazy conflicts when all those so called tabbed sliders were all residing on the page at once.